# ADF Copy activity inside foreach activity overwrite content in the sink

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm new to ADF and I'm using a copy activity inside a foreach activity. the problem which i'm facing is every time the foreach activity executes, the copy activity overwrites the content in the sink(file stored in a container).

My question is, is there a way to make copy activity to add the content at the end of the file instead of overwriting data please ?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Copy Activity **doesn't support append behavior.**

**Workaround** – Sink data in a separate file and then use `MergeFiles` option.

[image]

Refer - [Is it possible to append data for file in ADLS using ADF copy activity?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ea0b12f3-bba0-4ec0-b4d5-0c126de2bc37/is-it-possible-to-append-data-for-file-in-adls-using-adf-copy-activity?forum=AzureDataLake)

Comment: Thank you abhishekhandave for your reply. Yes this is the only solution exists now is use the merge file options. by the way I'm usinfg foreach activity because it iterates an array and pass the value to the copy activity then the copy activity call an api at the source and store the date at the sink in container with a different name the I add a different copy activity to merge the fime but the problem with approach is, I'm facinf some performance issues it takes much time to merge the files